# How to properly scale and position images inside of containers using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, flexbox

I am trying to create a meme page and have containers filled with images. Some images are wide and some are super long, I want to display them in a way such that the container is of set size (for example 50% screen width, height can be auto) and the image inside is cropped and centered. I think it is best to illustrate it with some photos.

This is what I want:

[image]

And this is what I am getting:

[image]

The key is getting these white stripes on the top and bottom if the image is too wide and left and right if the image is too long.

Here is my CSS code:

```css
.homePage {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 80px);
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.homePage .post {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.post .postHeader {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.postHeader .title {
  flex: 50%;
}
.postHeader .deletePost {
  flex: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.deletePost button {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.post .postImgContainer {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content:center;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

And my HTML code:

```html
<div className="homePage">
      {imageLists.map((image) => {
        return (
          <div className="post">
            <div className="postHeader">
              <div className="title"></div>
            </div>
            <div className="postImgContainer">
              {" "}
              <img src={image}></img>{" "}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
</div>
```

Whenever I change flex-direction from `column` to `row` in `.postImgContainer` it seems to be working, but only for one case of images, the other are getting stretched out.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: where's your html code? Add a working snippet so you can get help quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using flex, you can position the image in the desired position depending on the maximum width and height stipulated in the image container. I hope you can see it clearly with this example, let me know if you really need something else.

Try this:

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

.meme {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 15px auto;
  height: 600px;
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.meme-img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="meme">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/05/30/14/24/stairs-7231312_960_720.jpg" class="meme-img">
    </div>
    <div class="meme">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/29/14/38/web-1012467_960_720.jpg" class="meme-img">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Allow CSS backgrounds to work magic. We can add a background image instead of an actual image, prevent repeat, center it, and contain it.

Take a look at my (dumbed-down) version:

```css
.wrapper {
  /* let's pretend it's a square */
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  /* the trick is background images (see HTML)
     we use some styles here to make it all work */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  /* just for the demo */
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 7px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/600/300);"></div>
<p><!-- an empty spacer --></p>
<div class="wrapper" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/300/600);"></div>
```